# how to break parent function based on a child outcome in google app script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I break the parent function depending from a child function's outcome as a way of checking everything in case something is not ok in a child function? I currently have the following:

```
function Parent() { 
  Step1();
  Step2();
  Step3(); 
}
```

and I would like to break the parent function if child function "Step1()" is not completed, for example.

I thought I could create a global variable as a flag, combined with an if statement within the parent function such that if the flag would change from "true" to "false" **within** the **child** function, the whole parent function would break, but this didn't work giving an error saying the "break is illegal". This is what I tried:

```
var flag = "true" // Global variable

function Parent() { 
  Step1(); //Within this child function, I have an "if" condition that sets flag "true"/"false" depending on the outcome

     if (flag == "false") { //I was hoping this would read the incoming flag and trigger a break, if the flag was set to "false" in Step1();
     }

  Step2();

  Step3(); 
}
```

Right now my script goes through all child functions even if Step1() is incorrect, and without a way to stop this sequence, I'll just keep getting undesirable results from the parent function.

I also thought that if I used "break;" at **any** point in the whole .gs file it would break the whole thing but it's not the case. If I run Step1() on its **own** and the "if" conditions activate the "break;"  it breaks succesfully, but when I run the parent function it just keeps going onto the next function.

Thanks,
Nestor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To successfully break, add a [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

> The return statement **ends** function execution

```
if (flag == "false") { return; }
```

Alternatively, you could [`throw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) a error or play with [`try...catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Live snippet:

```js
let flag = 0;
function main() {
  console.info("main1");
  function step1() {
    console.info('step1');
    flag = 1;
  }
  function step2() {
    console.info('step2');
  }
  step1();
  if (flag) return; //stops execution
  step2();
}

function main2() {
  console.info("main2");
  function step1() {
    console.info('step1');
  }
  function step2() {
    console.info('step2');
    throw new Error('Step 2 fatal error');
  }
  function step3() {
    console.info('step3');
  }
  try {
    step1();
    step2();
    step3();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e.message);
  }
}
main();
main2();
```

Comment: hi @TheMaster , thanks for the clarification, this worked! Reading back on my initial code it's obvious I needed that "return" in the parent function.... Another thing I noticed is that without this flag method, using only a "return" in a child function is not strong enough to end the entire parent function. Is this normal for javascript? or is there another type of return-like function that would indeed end the parent function from inside a child one?

Comment: @Nestor Throwing a error will stop all executions. `return` will only stop the current function's execution(be it child's or parent's)

Answer (score 0):

apply blow logic

```
   let flag = true;
    function(){
        if (flag == "false") { 
            "false" in child1();
            goto lineContinue
         }

     child2();
     child3();

    }

    lineContinue: child4();
```

Comment: hi Muhammad, thanks for the help. I preferred opting for TheMaster's approach because it simpler. But for learning purposes, how would you implement the line "...{"false" in child1() ;"? This threw me off a little when I tried it because I don't know if there's a "in" function. Or maybe you meant this line as a comment?

Comment: @Nestor I hope my solution will help you at some point in future